# Verification of Alternate Proof for Identity Theorem in Conplex Analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Can't we prove Identity Theorem like this.

> IDENTITY THEOREM.
>   Consider a function which is analytic on an open connected domain $D$, if the set of zeros of $f$ has a limit point in $D$ then $f=0$ on $D$.

My Proof Idea.
If it is not $0$ identically then since the zeros of $f$ has a limit point in $D$ say $z_0$.
By continuity of $f$ we have  $f(z_0)=0$ and since $z_0$ is a limit point of set of zeros it is not isolated.
Thus $z_0$ being a zero of the non-constant analytic function $f$ is not isolated.
This contradicts the fact that  *An non-constant analytic function has isolated zeros.*

Hence our assumption is wrong and f is a constant function with value being zero.

Comment: Where have you used connectedness of $D$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown . So that may work even when D is not connected?   By the way is there any fault in reasoning?

Comment: It's a bit hard to check this since your proof isn't clearly worded. Please try to be more detailed and careful in your wording. That being said, connectedness is a technical condition here, since if our set is the disjoint union of the sets $A$ and $B$ and $f$ is identically zero on $A$ and identically one on $B$ then $f$ is in fact analytic on the domain $A \cup B. $

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the error in your proof is in the last line, when you use the fact that *a non-constant function has isolated zeros*. This is definitely true if your domain is $\mathbb{C}, $ which is probably the version you are thinking of, but is false in general. For example, let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint and define a function $f$ by $f \equiv 0$ on $A$ and $f \equiv 1$ on $B.$ Then $f$ is analytic on $A \cup B$ and has non-isolated zeros but is not constant.

The theorem you are looking for is this:

*given a function $f\colon A \to B$, if $f$ has an accumulation point of zeros on some domain (i.e. open and connected) $C \subseteq A$ then $f$ is constant on $C$.*

This phenomenon is more general throughout math, and is related to topology. For example, via purely topological methods we can show that if a function is locally constant on a connected component then it is globally constant on the whole connected component, but we cannot conclude the function is constant elsewhere.

*Note: you should also use the assumption that $D$ is open, since if our limit point is on the boundary the Identity Theorem can fail. Note this is part of the theorem you should be using above.*